# cakephp, how to store variables to be reusable inside another functions?

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

i  have a controller with multiple functions that have a variable inside them. I would like to access those variables from another function. Any ideas?

```
class RoomsController extends AppController {

public $helpers = array('Js' => 'Jquery');
public $components = array('RequestHandler');

function test1(){
        $balcony = $_REQUEST['qwe'];
        $this->set('qwe',$qwe);
}
function test2() {
        $occy = $_REQUEST['wer'];
        $this->set('wer',$wer);
}

function test3() {
        $deck = $_REQUEST['ert'];
        $this->set('ert',$ert);
}

function success() {
    // i want to use $qwe, $wer and $ert here   
}
```

any ideas on how to do this? do i have to set up global variables `public $qwe;`?

thanks

Comment: When are you calling `success()`? *Usually* you wouldn't call it in the same request as any of the other controller actions, so the question *should* be moot.

Comment: You can use session -> http://book.cakephp.org/view/1312/write

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create controller properties but it will break the design of the framework, so I suggest using Configuration class for this purpose, you can store variable values and retrieve using this class, here's a documentation:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/42/The-Configuration-Class

You can store variables in Session if you need their values after redirect:

```
$this -> Session -> write("variable", "value");
```

and retrieve:

```
$this -> Session -> read("variable");
```

Comment: can you give an example based on my example?

Comment: What variables are you trying to set as global?

Comment: i want to use them inside `function success(){}`

Comment: you need them to be avaliable after redirect?

Answer (score 1):

You can do with the use of CakePHP session

```
$this->Session->write('qwe', $qwe);\\ in test1

$qwe= $this->Session->read('qwe'); \\ in sucess
```

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1312/write

Though there are many mistake's and ambiguity in the code.

```
function test1(){
    $balcony = $_REQUEST['qwe'];
    $this->set('qwe',$qwe);            
}
```

Here you are taking request value in `$balcony` while you setting qwe with `$qwe` . And you are doing same thing in all function, I think you have to check this out.

Also as `deceze` said you are not using the flow of success function properly.

Comment: i am posting from a form through ajax to the controller. I have 3 forms and i post all three of them to the same controller. then i want to grab all those values and use them in another function in the same controller

Comment: can you give me an example of using the session in my case? to set and get it?

Comment: Use like: `$this->Session->write('qwe', $qwe);`